# Windows 8 drive shows no space but no data is inside

Tags: windows-8, disk-space

So D drive shows 85% consumption where inside the drive sub folder sums up to only 20% of the space.

[image]

I have already checked for the hidden files. I also used windirstat too which showing few extra files inside D drive's $recycle.bin folder but when I actually access that folder it comes out to be empty.

Not sure which data is consuming space.

[image]

Attaching windirstat screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Download and run DiskState and it will show you in a very obvious way where your space is being used. The more complex approach is to use a good file manager (that actually shows all hidden files). Probably it's a System Volume Information or something similar.